# How to exclude folders and directory path from find command

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I've got the following command

```
find /tmp/sjohal/archivetest > list
```

However I need the output to show the filenames in the folder without the directory path.

What is the best way to do this?

My current output looks as follows:

```
/tmp/sjohal/archivetest
/tmp/sjohal/archivetest/test2
/tmp/sjohal/archivetest/test1
/tmp/sjohal/archivetest/test3
/tmp/sjohal/archivetest/list.txt
```

I only require the output to show the files:

```
test2
test1
test3
```

Answer (score 0):

For all the files in the directory (without subdirectories)

```
find /tmp/sjohal/archivetest -maxdepth 1 ! -name 'list.txt' -type f -printf "%f\n"
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to have worked except it still includes the output in the list. When I do find /tmp/sjohal/archivetest -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%f\n" > out

Answer (score 0):

Try using ls command:
ls /tmp/sjohal/archivetest > list.txt